# Setting up simple struts 1.3 project, cannot find bean in ant scope

Tags: java, model-view-controller, servlets, javabeans, struts1

I am just starting out with struts to maintain a struts 1.3 application and after setting everything up and deploying my hello world application I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Cannot find bean: "helloWorldForm" in any scope
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:865)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:794)
org.apache.jsp.HelloWorld_jsp._jspService(HelloWorld_jsp.java:75)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:388)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
```

**My action class looks like this:**

```
package com.mkyong.common.action;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;

import com.mkyong.common.form.HelloWorldForm;

public class HelloWorldAction extends Action
{

public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    HelloWorldForm helloWorldForm = (HelloWorldForm) form;
    helloWorldForm.setMessage("Hello World! Struts");

    return mapping.findForward("success");
}


}
```

**My form class like this:**

```
package com.mkyong.common.form;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;

public class HelloWorldForm extends ActionForm{

    String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    }
```

**struts-config.xml like this:**

```
<form-beans>
    <form-bean name="helloWorldForm" 
        type="com.mkyong.common.form.HelloWorldForm"/>
</form-beans>

<action-mappings>
    <action path="/helloWorld"
        type="com.mkyong.common.action.HelloWorldAction"
        name="helloWorldForm">
        <forward name="success" path="/HelloWorld.jsp"/>

    </action>
</action-mappings>
```

**HelloWorld.jsp like this:**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1><bean:write name="helloWorldForm" property="message" />
</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I honestly just wanted to build upon this but could not quite get this to work and wondered if anyone might point me in the right direction.

Any help and advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is the reason that do not call directly the page of JSP just try to access the action Class using Action.

for this example try to access using Action of "/helloworld.do"

and ya you can access and print that variable on jsp page using Bean name that you have define into the

that way problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Yes so I do deserve a bit of a kicking; i was trying to access the jsp page prior to the action being completed hence why i got the error. I should have accessed the url as follows:

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample/helloWorld.do
```

I was trying the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/StrutsExample/HelloWorld.jsp
```

whoops -_-

Answer (score 0):

I just change path="/HelloWorld" look like path="/HelloWorld.jsp"/>
with "h" is uppcase

```
 <action path="/HelloWorld"
        type="com.mkyong.common.action.HelloWorldAction"
        name="helloWorldForm">
        <forward name="success" path="/HelloWorld.jsp"/>
    </action>
```